# Best Approach to update Object field in trigger before udpate

Tags: trigger

I have an object `class__c`. I need to update field boolean field taken as true or false on the basic of order field. `Taken__c` field is not comming while loading records, `Order__C` is comming in file.

```
public void handleBeforeUpdate(Class__c[] newClasses,Map<Id,Class__C> oldMapOfClasses){

    **for(class__c classes:newClasses){
        some things like if(classes.order__c==1){
            classes.taken__c=True;
        }
    }** 

}
```

What should be best bulkifield approach to it?

Comment: Are you looking for us to write this for you? What have you tried

Comment: @EricSSH Thanks for quick response.I was just looking if this will bulkified..Like For(class__c classes:newClasses){ if (classes.order__c==1){classes.Taken__C=1;}}

Comment: Bulkification is primarily about executing logic for sets of objects when executing that logic per object would run into the platform's governor limits (such as the number of SOQL queries). Executing simple logic such as your example per object is perfectly normal and does not require any reorganisation for the bulk case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can get you started..

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_qs_HelloWorld.htm

Trailhead also has many tutorials

https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_intro